# how to create a world street map with r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, spatial

I want to create a world street map using Rstudio. I have this code:

```
countries_map <-map_data("world")
world_map<-ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data = countries_map, 
           map = countries_map,aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region, group = group),
           fill = "light blue", color = "black", size = 0.1)
```

the problem: I want to see the names of the countries and to see the map like this one:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `leaflet` package. See this link to learn the choice of base map (https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/). Here I used the "Esri.WorldStreetMap", which is the same as your example image shows.

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldStreetMap") %>%
  setView(0, 0, zoom = 1)
```

[image]

In addition to `leaflet`, here I further introduced two other packages to create interactive maps, which are `tmap` and `mapview`.

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(tmap)

# Gett the World sf data
data("World")

# Turn on the view mode in tmap
tmap_mode("view")

# Plot World using tmap
tm_basemap("Esri.WorldStreetMap") +
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons(col = "continent")
```

[image]

```
# Plot world using mapview
mapview(World, map.types = "Esri.WorldStreetMap")
```

[image]

**Update**

Here is a way toa add text to each polygon using the `tmap` package.

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(tmap)

# Gett the World sf data
data("World")

# Turn on the view mode in tmap
tmap_mode("plot")

# Plot World using tmap
tm_basemap("Esri.WorldStreetMap") +
  tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_text(text = "iso_a3")
```

[image]

If you have to use `ggplot2`, you can prepare your into data as an `sf` object and use `geom_sf` and `geom_sf_text` as follows.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(ggplot2)

# Gett the World sf data
data("World")

ggplot(World) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = iso_a3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is an option to create the map without an interactive map? only to see the map with countries name and etc..? Thank you!

Comment: @LiranBenZion The base map you asked for is a typical online interactive setting, so what you are asking is confusing.

Comment: OK I understand. I will try to explain my self: at my code, I see the world map without names. I try to see the map with names..is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: @LiranBenZion Glad to help. If my post solves your question, please accept it as the answer.