# ggplot2 add continent names to a world map plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm using maps and ggplot 2 to create a world map plot that shows continents in a different colour based on some results (that I've added to the country coordinates). So far, so good. **However, I'm struggling with adding the continent names to the map**, i.e. I want to add "Asia" on the orange part in the plot, "LATAM" to the blue part and so on. Not sure how to do that.

I thought about calculating the geographical mid point for each continent (which will become problematic when including overseas regions like for UK or Greenland for Denmark) or trying to find a representative country for each continent and draw the name at that position, e.g. for Asia, I could draw the name "Asia" at China's position. But I also don't know how to do that.

Here's my code so far and the current plot:

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

world = map_data("world")
```

! I'm not sure how to show in a code example here, but I have a matching file that I'm merging with the world map that contains the continental region `region` of each country (e.g. Asia, or Africa)

```
# Here I create some dummy results data for each region    
results = data.frame(region = c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "NA", "Oceania", "SA"),
                     kpi    = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

# Joining the dummy results with the worldmap data    
results_world = inner_join(world, results, by = "region")


plain <- theme(
  axis.text = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  axis.title = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
)

ggplot(data = results_world,
                    aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = kpi)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = region)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", direction = 1) +
  plain
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image: Raw World Map]

whereas I want to have sth. like this (I know that some countries are missing, e.g. in Africa, I'm still searching for a comprehensive file in the www containing a) all countries, b) their geographical continents and c) their political affiliation):

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801030/filling-countries-and-continents-with-maps-library-according-to-variable-value)?

Comment: @DavidKlotz that post doesn't involve placing labels, which is what this OP is missing

Comment: If you can switch to an `sf` object for the shape, you can use `geom_sf` and `geom_sf_text` to do this without calculating midpoints or centroids. Otherwise, calculate the centroid of each polygon and add labels with `geom_text` / `geom_label`. Several related posts are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038640/labeling-center-of-map-polygons-in-r-ggplot), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9441436/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28962453/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50859765/5325862), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54964279/5325862)

Comment: Thanks camille. I will check out these sources and let you know if I succeeded.

Comment: @camille Sorry, I'm still struggling, so with the help of your first link I managed to read in a shape file, the problem of the mentioned solution there is that it calculates the centroids based on the countries and I don't know a way to calculate the centroids based on the continents. The second link, however, at least shows a solution how to get the mean position of each continent, but it's too off. So I'm wondering (still looking at the first link) how to calculate the centroid per continent.

Comment: If you have 2 shapefiles, one where each polygon is a country and one where each polygon is a continent, calculating the centroids of each polygon shouldn't have any different procedures

Comment: True, although it's difficult to find a nice continental shape file. It seems that shapefiles are mostly done for countries, so I was wondering how to aggregate these polygons into continental ones for which I then could calculate the centroid.

Comment: In that case, your first step would be to take a shapefile of countries and dissolve / union it into continents. There should be several SO posts on this already as well. When I googled "world continent shapefile" I found [this one](https://apps.gis.ucla.edu/geodata/dataset/continent_ln)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the help of some links I found two potential solutions:

[Labeling center of map polygons in R ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038640/labeling-center-of-map-polygons-in-r-ggplot)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63577/joining-polygons-in-r/273515

As @camille mentioned, it basically boils down to reshaping/dissolving the original country shape file into continents.

An alternative is to manually create a small data frame where I put in the coordinate positions of each continent and add is as a text layer to a plot.

Here are the two solutions for combining/dissolving the country shapefile to a continent one:

**1. Solution: dissolving in the original shaepfile / polygons object**

```
library(rgdal)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)
library(svglite)
library(tidyverse)
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)


### First part is about downloading shapefiles

# load shape files
# download.file("http://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/packages/natural_earth_vector.zip",
#               "world maps.zip")
# 
# unzip("folder\\world maps.zip",
#       exdir = "folder\\Raw maps from zip")

### Next part is bringing the world data into the right shape and enrich with the my results
###

# read in the shape file
world = readOGR(dsn   = "folder\\Raw maps from zip\\110m_cultural",
                layer = "ne_110m_admin_0_countries")

# Reshape the world data so that polygons are continents not countries
world_id    = world@data$CONTINENT
world_union = unionSpatialPolygons(world, world_id)

# Bring it into tidy format
world_fortified = tidy(world_union, region = "CONTINENT")

# Here I create some dummy survey results
results = data.frame(id             = c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "North America", "Oceania", "South America"),
                     kpi            = c(20, 30, 50, 50, 60, 70),
                     continent_long = c(15, 80, 20, -100, 150, -60),
                     continent_lat  = c(15, 35, 50, 40, -25, -15),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

# Combine world map with results and drop Antarctica and seaven Seas
world_for_plot = world_fortified %>%
  left_join(., results, by = "id") %>%
  filter(!is.na(kpi))

### plot the results.

# Let's create the plot first wit data and let's care about the labels later
plain <- theme(
  axis.text = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  axis.title = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
)

# This is the actual results plot with different colours based on the results
raw_plot = ggplot(data = world_for_plot,
                  aes(x = long,
                  y = lat,
                  group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = kpi)) +
  coord_equal(1.3) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn", direction = 1) +
  labs(fill = "kpi") +
  plain

## Now automatically adding label positions form the shapefile

# We start with getting the centroid positions of each continent and delete the continents we don't have
position = coordinates(world_union)

position = data.frame(position, row.names(position))
names(position) = c("long", "lat", "id")

position = position %>%
  filter(id %in% world_for_plot$id)

# We can now refer to this new data in our previously created plot object
final_plot = raw_plot +
  geom_text(data = position,
            aes(label = id,
                x = long,
                y = lat,
                group = id))

# But we can also put in the continent coordinates manually. I already created some coordinates in the results object
# So we can easily use this data instead of the above calculated positions.
final_plot = raw_plot +
  geom_text(data = results,
            aes(label = id,
                x = continent_long,
                y = continent_lat,
                group = id))
```

**2. Solution: Using sf objects in a more data frame like way**

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# I dropped the part of downloading the shapefile here. See solution 1 for that.

world = read_sf(dsn   = "folder\\Raw maps from zip\\110m_cultural",
                layer = "ne_110m_admin_0_countries")

# Next we just do some tidy magic and group the data by CONTINENT and get the respective coordinates in a long list
continents = world %>%
  group_by(CONTINENT) %>%
  summarise(.)

# Here I create some dummy survey results
results = data.frame(CONTINENT      = c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "North America", "Oceania", "South America"),
                     kpi         = c(20, 30, 50, 50, 60, 70),
                     continent_long = c(15, 80, 20, -100, 150, -60),
                     continent_lat  = c(15, 35, 50, 40, -25, -15),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

# Now let's join the continent data with the results
world_for_plot = continents %>%
  left_join(., results, by = c("CONTINENT")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(kpi))

### Now we can plot the results.

# Let's create the plot first with data and let's care about the labels later
plain <- theme(
  axis.text = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  axis.title = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
)

# This is the actual results plot with different colours based on the results
raw_plot = ggplot(data = world_for_plot) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = kpi),
          colour=NA) +
  coord_sf() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn", direction = 1) +
  plain

# Now we can add the labels
final_plot = raw_plot +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label=CONTINENT))

# We could also use our own label positions
final_plot = raw_plot +
  geom_text(aes(label = CONTINENT,
                   x = continent_long,
                   y = continent_lat,
                   group = CONTINENT))
```

Happy to hear your thoughts about it.

Please note that the plot below is the one where I actually manually positioned the labels.

[image]